# Building maven spring boot project throws error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

I am new to spring boot. I am trying to migrate project from old spring boot to the latest version.

I changed the version of spring boot in project. But when i build the project it fails in tests throwing computational failure with error below

**`package org.springframework.test.annotation does not exist`**

I have this dependency in my project

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Not sure what i could be missing?

Comment: please mention the old version and the new version

Comment: I would guess that Maven corrupted the `spring-test` jar (a dependency on `spring-boot-test`) when it downloaded it. Try clearing out your Maven cache and building your application again.

Comment: after I added spring-boot-starter-test instead of spring-boot-test it worked. what is the difference between the both and when to use which?

Answer (score 0):

Change `spring-boot-test` TO `spring-boot-starter-test` like below :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Refer http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters for more info about starters.